# Bigquery registers null as int64

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery, below mentioned query works well:

```
select 
  col1=col2 as col3 
from (
  select 
    null as col1,
    cast(null as string) as col2  
  union all
    select 
    "abc" as col1,
    "abc" as col2  
)
```

It results:

| Row | col3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | true |

But if I modify query to:

```
select 
  col1=col2 as col3 
from (
  select 
    null as col1,
    cast(null as string) as col2  
)
```

It gives me error:

`No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [2:3]`

Why is the first null in subquery being treated as int64 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery infers the data type based on the context or surrounding expressions.
So, in your first example - it is clear that col1 is a string because of following union all values.
In second example  - no any way to identify the type, so default type is used - which is int64